# How to strip non-letter characters from beginning and end of a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, strip

I need to remove all non-letter characters from the beginning and from the end of a word, but keep them if they appear between two letters.

For example:

```
'123foo456' --> 'foo'
'2foo1c#BAR' --> 'foo1c#BAR'
```

I tried using `re.sub()`, but I couldn't write the regex.

Comment: Is this a single string, or will the string contain multiple words?

Comment: The string have multiple words, but I am interested only in the individual words. I am first performing a `split()` and the iterating over the list of words. I think building the regex for the single word should be user, and that's OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

like this?

```
re.sub('^[^a-zA-Z]*|[^a-zA-Z]*$','',s)
```

`s` is the input string.

Comment: I was wondering if there would be any difference if we replaced the `*` with a `+` in the regex above?

Answer (score 7):

You could use [str.strip](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) for this:

```
In [1]: import string

In [4]: '123foo456'.strip(string.digits)
Out[4]: 'foo'

In [5]: '2foo1c#BAR'.strip(string.digits)
Out[5]: 'foo1c#BAR'
```

As Matt points out in the comments (thanks, Matt), this removes digits only. To remove any non-letter character,

Define what you mean by a non-letter:

```
In [22]: allchars = string.maketrans('', '')

In [23]: nonletter = allchars.translate(allchars, string.letters)
```

and then strip:

```
In [18]: '2foo1c#BAR'.strip(nonletter)
Out[18]: 'foo1c#BAR'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there exist non letter characters that are not in string.digits. `!@#$%^&*(()` come to mind

Answer (score 2):

With your two examples, I was able to create a regex using Python's non-greedy syntax as described [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).  I broke up the input into three parts: non-letters, exclusively letters, then non-letters until the end.  Here's a test run:

```
1:[123]   2:[foo]   3:[456]
1:[2]   2:[foo1c#BAR]   3:[]
```

Here's the regular expression:

```
^([^A-Za-z]*)(.*?)([^A-Za-z]*)$
```

And `mo.group(2)` what you want, where `mo` is the MatchObject.

Answer (score 2):

To be unicode compatible:

```
^\PL+|\PL+$
```

`\PL` stands for for `not a letter`

Comment: right, but python `re` doesn't support that. You need http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
re.sub(r'^[^a-zA-Z]*(.*?)[^a-zA-Z]*$', '\1', string);
```

The round brackets capture everything between non-letter strings at the beginning and end of the string. The `?` makes sure that the `.` does not capture any non-letter strings at the end, too. The replacement then simply prints the captured group.

Answer (score 0):

`result = re.sub('(.*?)([a-z].*[a-z])(.*)', '\\2', '23WERT#3T67', flags=re.IGNORECASE)`